# CSS nth-child transform translate calculations slight bug

Tags: html, css

Im having a little issue with changing the positions correctly on some lists.

JSFiddle quick mock up: https://jsfiddle.net/3Lu3cafj/

I have list items as normal...

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

However on mobile i need to change the positions of the items so the images show left and right as desktop they are side by side so trying to make it do...

1
3
2
5
4
7
6
8

If you see what i mean, just swapping a little like odd and even... sorry if made mistake on second number example but will see what i mean with code i currently have. The code i have works.... but seems  on an even amount does not show the last item

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .collection-list {
    .collection-list-item {
      .collection-list-hover-button {
        .button { 
          padding: 5px 8px !important;
          border: 1px solid #ffffff !important;
        }
      }
      &.collection-hover {
        width: 100% !important;
        margin-left: 0 !important;
      margin-bottom: 0px !important;

        &:nth-child(2n){
          margin-left: 0;
        }
        &:nth-child(4n - 2) {
          -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
          -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
          transform: translateY(100%);
        }
        &:nth-child(4n - 1) {
          -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
          -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
          transform: translateY(-100%);
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>
    even amount
    </h1>
    
    <ul class="collection-list">
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 1">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 2">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 3">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 4">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 5">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 6">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 7">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 8">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 9">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 10">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    
    
    
    <h1 style="clear: both;margin-top: 3em;">
    odd amount
    </h1>
    
    <ul class="collection-list">
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 1">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 2">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 3">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 4">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 5">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 6">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 7">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 8">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 9">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 10">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 11">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 12">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 13">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 14">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="collection-list-item grid-item first collection-hover">
        <a href="/collections/butterfly-sofa" class="position-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=image 15">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Can see it not showing the last item here: https://www.ambientlounge.eu/collections/outdoor-bean-bags

but on other section shows all and can only work out because this one has an even amount and one above does not but might be wrong....

https://www.ambientlounge.eu/collections/indoor-bean-bags

You only see this changing of position on mobile / or viewport of a mobile size

Comment: anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is something `flex` is made for, using the `order` property on flex children.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
@media (max-width: 420px) {
  li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(3) {
    order: -3;
  }
  li:nth-child(2), li:nth-child(5) {
    order: -2;
  }
  li:nth-child(4), li:nth-child(7) {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I use to avoid flex as browser support but good these days so all good, however seems only works up to 8, anyway to make it it work regardless of amount?